# Excel table filters not recognised in PowerPivot measures

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to create a parameter table to change the units the figures in my pivot table are presented in. I have:

- TransTBL table with my transactions.
- Units table with 1; 1,000; 1,000,000 in column A and Units; K's; M's in column B.

Both tables are in my data model.

I added the Units Column B as a slicer to TransTBL, despite the fact they have no connections.

I then tried to create a measure in the Units table on the PowerPivot side to recognise which slicer option was chosen. My measure won't recognise the slicer selection. However it will recognise the filter if I apply it directly to the table in PowerPivot.

I'm using the HASONEVALUE function as described [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JbdCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=hasonevalue+works+on+model+filters+but+not+on+excel+filters&source=bl&ots=mNMN1P6zob&sig=pmpKqamwNoExvWIlRpNEqD9te0Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiglY25tZDSAhUW62MKHVakC90Q6AEITzAI#v=onepage&q=hasonevalue%20works%20on%20model%20filters%20but%20not%20on%20excel%20filters&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

The measure works fine as expected.

```
AmountDisplay = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(Units[B]),
    SUM(TransTBL[Amount]) / VALUES(Units[A]),
    SUM(TransTBL[Amount])
)
```

[image: result]

Can you provide more details on your data or model to see if there are any specific problems associated?